# How to override 1/x operator in python

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I'm creating a class in python which I want to use with my custom arithmetic algorithms. To operate on its instances, I have overridden all its operator functions, such as __add__, __mul__, __truediv__, etc.

For example, say it is a *complex* class:

```
class complex:
    def __init__(self,module,phase):
        self.module = module
        self.phase = phase
    def __mul__(self,other):
        return complex(self.module + other.module, self.phase + other.phase)
    def __truediv__(self,other):
        return complex(self.module / other.module, self.phase - other.phase)
```

I want to be able to write expressions as:

```
from math import pi
a = complex(1,0.5*pi)
b = 1/a
```

but if I do so, I will get the following error:

**unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'complex'**

While I would have wanted the result of

```
b = complex(1,0) / a
```

What do I have to override to make it work?

EDIT:

Thanks to [hiro protagonist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4954037/hiro-protagonist)'s comment, I've just discovered the whole new world of [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)

Comment: you may have to implement [`__rtruediv__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rtruediv__) to make `1/a` work.

Comment: Don't use the name `complex` for your class, since it will mask Python's built-in `complex` class (which you'd be better off using instead of creating your own).  So call yours something like `my_complex` to decouple it from the Python implementation.

Comment: The _complex_ class is just an example. There are other cases where one could want to implement a fully functional new numeric type. Also, one could want to reimplement the complex class for didactic purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `__rtruediv__(self,other)` which is the function used when your object is on the right side of the division.

and perhaps also for the other operators:

```
def __radd__(self, other):       ... 
def __rsub__(self, other):       ...
def __rmul__(self, other):       ...
def __rmatmul__(self, other):    ...
def __rfloordiv__(self, other):  ...
def __rmod__(self, other):       ...
def __rdivmod__(self, other):    ...
```

You can define these using the others you already have:

```
def __rtruediv__(self,other):
    return complex(other,0).__truediv__(self)
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not use the in-built `complex` type and [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html)?

```
a = 1+2j
b = 1/a
```